# Linux permission issue, when accessing I2C - Jetson Nano

Tags: linux, i2c, adc, nano, iio

I am building a small Jetson Nano robot and have done everything myself so far, from the battery pack up to spare parts for 12 V reduced engines, a Lidar, a night vision camera and an ADC to measure battery power. The script below I wrote to have a small App pop up in the desktop corner and show the actual battery, I have attached a small monitor to the robots back.

If I call the script with `sudo`, it works as intended, even can fork it as a process. Yet if I try to autostart it any other way, it does not work. Then I get the error:

"NameError: name 'I2C' is not defined"

The issue is related to the Python libs board, `busio` and `adafruit` accompanying the script. There is an issue about it on their GitHub and the solution is to either downgrade `busio` or upgrade the whole lib package to a newer version. In fact on the Jetson Nano I am running version 6.15, tho the actual version is 8 something. Problem is that `pip` doesn't allow greater than v6.15, I'd need to upgrade Python then. I don't want to do this on the Nano, since it's working perfectly with the current setup in image segmentation and therefore pathfinding.
Downgrading `busio` I tried as far as I could go, had no effect though.

So I am basically trieing to find out a permission/recognition thing. If I execute the script with `sudo` as a user it runs. If I do the following, I get the error:

- run the script as root
- run it with `pkexec`
- run it as a `systemctl` script

So it seems to always happen as root, what I haven't tried yet is a `crontab`, though prolly as root the same will happen.

Do you maybe have an idea, what else I could do? The only thing I basically want to achieve is that the script autostarts on a reboot.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1015 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn

from tkinter import Tk,Label

# Create the I2C bus
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# Create the ADC object using the I2C bus
ads = ADS.ADS1015(i2c)

# Create single-ended input on channel 0
chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)

# factor voltage divider
v_divider = 5.54546

# draw GUI

root = Tk()
root.title('Robot_No6_BatMon')

w = 150 # width for the Tk root
h = 50 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = ws - (w)
y = 0

# set the dimensions of the screen 
# and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

Label(root, text="Battery Percentage Left:", font=("Arial", 25)).pack()

def update_text():
    # Calculate bat stats
    bat_percent = chan.voltage - 1.81
    bat_percent = bat_percent * 100
    curr_voltage = v_divider * chan.voltage
    curr_wattage = curr_voltage * 3.1

    if (bat_percent > 100):
        l.config(text="100 % / 16.8 Volt\n52 Wh")
    else:
        l.config(text="{:.0f} % / {:.1f} Volt\n{:.0f} Wh (52 Wh Design)".format(bat_percent, curr_voltage, curr_wattage))
    root.after(10000, update_text)

l = Label(root, text="", font=("Arial", 25))
l.pack()

update_text()
root.mainloop()
```

[Bat GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WATbi.png)

[Robot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3KRv.jpg)

Comment: There is a driver for this ADC in the Linux kernel, why don't you use it?